# When can I change a summation to an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, physics

Often in my engineering courses, professors just switch out a summation with an integral and change some extensive property to an infinitesimal quantity. This is something I have to accept, but I feel like I've never received rigorous justification for this.

For example, I'm working with products of inertia, defined as:
$$I_{xy} = \sum m_{i} (x_{i} y_{i}) ,$$

and I'm presented with the substitution
$$\sum m_{i} (x_{i} y_{i}) = \int_{\text{body}}^{} (yx)dm$$

which isn't defined anywhere in my textbook or online. I think I'm ready for an explanation of why this is a mathematically sound process.

EDIT: I did a quick derivation myself, tell me if I did anything hand-wavey
given the definition of the integral

> ! $$\int_{a}^{b} F(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_{i}) \Delta x_{i}$$
> and
> $$I_{xy} = \sum m_{i} (x_{i} y_{i}) $$
> where yi can be expressed explitily as some
> $$y_{i} = f(x_{i})$$
> under constant linear density define
> $$\Delta x  = \frac{b-a}{n},\,\ and\,\ m_{i} = m/n $$
> $$\lambda = \frac{m}{b-a} = \frac{\frac{m}{n}}{\frac{b-a}{n}}  =  \frac{m_{i}}{\Delta x} $$
> $$m_{i} = \frac{m}{b-a} \Delta x $$
> we get
> $$I_{xy} = \sum m_{i} (x_{i} y_{i}) = \frac{m}{b-a} \sum x_{i} f(x_{i}) \Delta x $$
> let
> $$x_i = a + i\cdot \Delta x$$
> then we can finally take the limit
> $$I_{xy} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i} y_{i}) = \frac{m}{b-a} \sum x_{i} f(x_{i}) \Delta x \\
> I_{xy} = \int_{a}^{b} x\cdot f(x) dx$$

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* mathematically sound.

What they can claim to be doing is passing to the limit, but that's not just how to do it.

Comment: Does there exist a mathematically sound method for summating an expression like that? For example if my expression $$\sum m_{i} (x_{i} y_{i})$$ is used in the example $$y = \frac{1}{2}x$$ where the system is defined as existing on the interval $$x ε [1,2]$$

Comment: @NickThorpe Again, what I think is meant is first partitioning the body into a finite number of discrete chunks, then repeating this *ad infinitum,* so that the number of chunks goes to infinity while each chunk becomes infinitesimal.